# Trying different functions until one does not throw an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some functions which try various methods to solve a problem based on a set of input data. If the problem cannot be solved by that method then the function will throw an exception.

I need to try them in order until one does not throw an exception.

I'm trying to find a way to do this elegantly:

```py
try:
    answer = method1(x,y,z)
except MyException:
    try:
        answer = method2(x,y,z)
    except MyException:
        try:
            answer = method3(x,y,z)
        except MyException:
            ...
```

In pseudo code what I'm aiming for is something along the lines of:

```py
tryUntilOneWorks:
    answer = method1(x,y,z)
    answer = method2(x,y,z)
    answer = method3(x,y,z)
    answer = method4(x,y,z)
    answer = method5(x,y,z)
except:
    # No answer found
```

To be clear: `method2` mustn't be called unless `method1` fails, and so on.

Comment: I would highly recommend reverting your question and asking another one. Your last edit completely invalidates my answer, which was otherwise fairly useful.

Comment: I rolled your question back to its original form. Please post a new question with your clarifications.

Comment: And please post a comment here with a link to the new question. I suspect you'll get an answer pretty fast that way.

Comment: You can get to the previous revision by clicking on the link  that (currently) says [edited ... mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57926936/revisions) over @Code-Apprentice's name (yours is Rev 3). I have an answer pretty much waiting for you.

Comment: Question ready to post but waiting on my 90 minute limit to posting questions.

Comment: Supplementary question now posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928250/trying-variations-on-a-function-call-until-one-completes-without-throwing-except

Comment: @MarkRogers. I didn't know there was a 90 minute limit. With the way your rep is going, I think that limit will be dropped for you pretty soon anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that Python functions are first class objects, you can add them to a sequence:

```
methods = [method1, method2, method3, ..., methodN]
```

Applying every item of the list to your arguments until one *doesn't* fail is straightforward in that case:

```
def find_one_that_works(*args, **kwargs):
    for method in methods:
        try:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except MyException:
            pass
    raise MyException('All methods failed')
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks. But it shows a flaw in my question asking: the parameters passed might not all be the same (specifically: in some cases I need to call the same function with different parameters, in others the different functions with the same parameters). Can it be generalised? (I'll update the question to clarify.)

Comment: @MarkRogers. Rather than invalidating the answer, ask another question.

Comment: This final solution will still pass the same arguments to all of the methods.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Yes, OP just changed the entire question out from under me.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Just about to ping him with some suggestions.

Comment: @MarkRogers It looks like Mad Physicist has answered your original question. Since you realize you were missing some details, you should post a new question that links back to this one for reference rather than just clarifying with a comment.

Comment: Sorry, saw your comment too late. Can't see how to roll it back?