# Trying variations on a function call until one completes without throwing exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

Related to [Trying different functions until one does not throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926936/)

I need to make multiple function calls, in sequence, until one returns without throwing an exception. The functions are carrying out different methods to solve a problem based on the input data.

In long form, the following works:

```py
try:
    answer = method1(data, x, y, z)
except MyException:
    try:
        answer = method2(data, x, y, z, factor=1.0)
    except MyException:
        try:
            answer = method3(data, x, y, z, factor=2.0)
        except MyException:
            ...
```

In psuedo-code my objective is something cleaner and easier to expand:

```py
tryUntilOneWorks:
    answer = method1(data, x, y, z)
    answer = method2(data, x, y, z, factor=1.0)
    answer = method2(data, x, y, z, factor=2.0)
    answer = method3(a, b, c)
    answer = method4(data)
except:
    # No answer found
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've answered a similar question before... the TL;DR is "use a loop".

Comment: Welp, I didn't realized you already had an answer. If the only problem is that all functions have a different signature, just replace them with new functions that all have the same signature - you can do that with lambdas or with `functools.partial`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey. I had a slightly different solution in mind.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're the first person who ever pinged me when they reopened a question I'd hammered! 

Comment: @Aran-Fey. I didn't know I could just unhammer it like that :)

Comment: @Aran-Fey. At this point I may as well tell you that I finished my answer. If you still think this should be closed, I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ideally I would've liked for both questions to be answered in a single place (let's be real here, an answer that only works with functions with identical signatures is pretty dang useless), but then again, SO is a disorganized junk heap anyway so it hardly matters. Do what you want; I've stopped caring long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Aran-Fey is suggesting is probably the simplest solution: create a list of function objects on the fly that call the methods that you want in the way that you want:

```
def find_one_that_works(data, a, b, c, x, y, z, factor1, factor2):
    methods = [
        lambda: method1(data, x, y, z),
        lambda: method2(data, x, y, z, factor=1.0),
        lambda: method2(data,x,y,z,factor=2.0),
        lambda: method3(a, b, c),
        lambda: method4(data),
    ]
    for method in methods:
        try:
            return method()
        except MyException:
            pass
    raise MyException('All methods failed')
```

This requires a good amount of hard-coding, so I would recommend something a bit more general. You could pass in all the possible arguments, keyword or otherwise, along with a spec for how to apply them to each function:

```
def find_one_that_works(methods, specs, *args, **kwargs):
    def get(k):
        return kwargs[k] if isinstance(k, str) else args[k]

    for method, (arg_spec, kwarg_spec) in zip(methods, specs):
        ar = [get(k) for k in arg_spec]
        kw = {k: get(v) for k, v in kwarg_spec.items()}
        try:
            return method(*ar, **kw)
        except MyException:
            pass
    raise MyException('None succeeded')
```

This allows you to specify a tuple of selections for the positional arguments and a mapping of selections for keyword arguments that will be extracted from everything you pass into the function. The example in your question would be called like this:

```
methods = [method1, method2, method2, method3, method4]
specs = [
    ((0, 4, 5, 6), {}),
    ((0, 4, 5, 6), {'factor': 7}),
    ((0, 4, 5, 6), {'factor': 8}),
    ((1, 2, 3), {}),
    ((0,), {})
]
find_one_that_works(methods, specs, data, a, b, c, x, y, z, 1.0, 2.0)
```

The nice thing is that you can name all your arguments this way too. The following is identical to the above:

```
methods = [method1, method2, method2, method3, method4]
specs = [
    (('data', 'x', 'y', 'z'), {}),
    (('data', 'x', 'y', 'z'), {'factor': 'factor1'}),
    (('data', 'x', 'y', 'z'), {'factor': 'factor2'}),
    (('a', 'b', 'c'), {}),
    (('data',), {})
]
find_one_that_works(methods, specs,
                    data=data, a=a, b=b, c=c,
                    x=x, y=y, z=z, factor1=1.0, factor2=2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that lambdas would be part of it but I'm new to Python (long time programmer but getting used to Python's features/quirks).